# How to get a result from a asynchronous task

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I'm a beginner using async in VB.NET. I read online help but some things aren't clear.
I try to use *[tweetinvi](https://linvi.github.io/tweetinvi/dist/index.html)* library

I got this:

```
Namespace tweet_invi
    Class twitter_call
        Public Shared Async Function twitter_get_user_info_from_id(id As Long) As Task

            Dim userClient = New TwitterClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerSecret"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("accessToken"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("accessTokenSecret"))

            Dim tweetinviUser = Await userClient.Users.GetUserAsync(id)

            Dim description As String = tweetinviUser.Description
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And the module from where i would launch this async function

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

   Dim toto As Long = 1311275527223812096
   Dim result = tweet_invi.twitter_call.twitter_get_user_info_from_id(toto)

End Sub
```

My issue: *result* is a task. How do i have to get the value of *description*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see it in the code you posted. The second line of that method does it. You use the `Await` operator to await the completion of the `Task`.

That said, there is no result to get anyway. If you have a synchronous `Sub` then that becomes an asynchronous `Function` that returns a `Task`. In both cases, there is no actual value to get out of the method. As such, awaiting such a method doesn't return anything. If you have a synchronous `Function` with a return type of `T` then that becomes an asynchronous `Function` that returns a `Task(Of T)`. Awaiting that gives you a result of type `T`.

If you had these methods:

```vb
Private Sub DoSomething()
    '...
End Sub

Private Function GetSomething() As SomeType
    '...
End Function
```

then you'd call them like this:

```vb
DoSomething()

Dim someValue As SomeType = GetSomething()
```

If you had these methods:

```vb
Private Async Function DoSomethingAsync() As Task
    '...
End Function

Private Async Function GetSomethingAsync() As Task(Of SomeType)
    '...
End Function
```

then you'd call them like this:

```vb
Await DoSomethingAsync()

Dim someValue As SomeType = Await GetSomethingAsync()
```

VB actually does support `Async Sub` but the ONLY time you should ever us it is for event handlers, which MUST be declared `Sub`, i.e. you cannot handle an event with a `Function`. Also, any method in which you want to use the `Await` operator must be declared `Async`. Together, that means that you must declare the `Click` event handler of your `Button` as `Async Sub` and then you can await an asynchronous method in it:

```vb
Private Async Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
   Dim toto As Long = 1311275527223812096

   Await tweet_invi.twitter_call.twitter_get_user_info_from_id(toto)
End Sub
```

With regards to the code you posted, that `twitter_get_user_info_from_id` method is useless. It declares and sets some local variables but does nothing with the data it gets. I suspect that that method should be like this:

```vb
Namespace tweet_invi
    Class twitter_call
        Public Shared Async Function twitter_get_user_info_from_id(id As Long) As Task(Of String)
            Dim userClient = New TwitterClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("consumerSecret"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("accessToken"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("accessTokenSecret"))
            Dim tweetinviUser = Await userClient.Users.GetUserAsync(id)
            Dim description As String = tweetinviUser.Description

            Return description
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

and then you would call it like this:

```vb
Private Async Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
   Dim toto As Long = 1311275527223812096
   Dim userInfo = Await tweet_invi.twitter_call.twitter_get_user_info_from_id(toto)

   '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this pristine answer!